# Ruby on Rails - метод для link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Привет. В моем контроллере есть экшен, который вызывается во вьюхе, какой метод он должен иметь?

экшен в контроллере:

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController

    def action_1
        @user = User.find_by(uid: params[:uid])
        @user.votes.pluck(:author_uid).delete(current_user.uid)
        current_user.user_votes.pluck(:recipient_uid).delete(@user.uid)
        redirect_to root_url
    end

end
```

ссылка в представлении:

```
= link_to 'Dislike', { controller: "votes", action: "action_1", uid: friend.uid }, method: "WHICH???"
```

Приведенный код во вьюхе работает некорректно: если верить логам передается GET и действия из action_1 не производятся.

Буду рад ,если подскажете, или укажете где ошибка.

Спасибо!

Comment: А что надо то?

Answer (score 1):

А в роутах что?
И укажите в method: "Post", например.
У меня кнопка на нестандартный метод работает так. 
В роутах

```
resources :tasks do
  post 'make_done', on: :member
end
```

И сама кнопка

```
button_to t(:set_done), make_done_task_path(task.id)
```

В контроллере

```
def make_done
end
```